# Issue with coordinate projection for detecting spatial autocorrelation in R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, projection, r-sp

We have a dataset that contains latitude and longitude coordinates, as well as attribute information, each in its own separate column, stored as numeric. These coordinates have been geocoded based on the geographic coordinate system WGS 1984. 
We know that we have significant spatial autocorrelation in our data, which we are hoping to visualize in a bubble plot using the “sp” package. We are modeling our example off of others online, such as here: https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/breaking-the-rules-with-spatial-correlation/ . However, when we try to use the coordinates command within "sp", we keep getting an error message:

Code example: 
coords <- data.frame(lead$X, lead$Y)
coordinates(coords) <- c("lead6.X","lead6.Y")

Error in if (nchar(projargs) == 0) projargs <- as.character(NA) missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

We can't load our direct code because it's sensitive and hosted on a virtual environment without access to the internet. Does anyone have ideas for why this might be happening? We've looked into the proj4 package but can't figure out how to specify a projection system (or is that even the error that we are getting?). If anyone knows of any other packages in R or ways to visualize spatial autocorrelation, those would be much appreciated too.

Comment: Try to recreate the error message with data that are not sensitive, and provide these in a reproducible example. Why not directly use `coords = SpatialPoints(data.frame(lead$X, lead$Y), CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit "strange": seems you are trying to build a dataset containing only coordinates. AFAIU, you may need something in this line :

```
data <- data.frame(lead$X, lead$Y, lead$Z)
```

,with lead$Z corresponding to a generic "variable" you want to inspect, then

```
coordinates(data) <- c('X','Y')`
proj4string(data) <- "+init=epsg:4326"
```

, which should give you a proper "SpatialPointsDataframe" with lat-lon WGS84 geographic coordinates (the first line could be also dropped, and you'll keep all variables in the data of the spatialpointsdataframe).

HTH